# Open Redirect or Header Manipulation issues from Fortify scan on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, redirect, fortify

We did a Fortify scan on our ASP.net application. We found that there many header manipulation issues. All the issues are pointing to Response.Redirect(). Please have a look at the below code where I encoded the parameters. Even then the below code is counted as header manipulation issue.

```
            int iCount = 0;
            foreach (string Name in Request.QueryString.Keys)
            {
                iCount++;
                if (iCount > 1)
                {
                    url += "&";
                }
                url += Name;
                if (Request.Params[Name]!=null)
                {
                    url += "=" + AntiXss.UrlEncode(Request.Params[Name]);
                }
            }
            Response.redirect(Server.UrlPathEncode(page.root) + "\Test.aspx?" + url);
```

Can some body let me know what else is required to change here to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 5):

Take off the `Server.UrlPathEncode(page.root)` portion and use `Server.Transfer()` instead of `Response.Redirect()`.

`Server.Transfer()` transfers the user to another page on the same site and poses little to no danger of accidentally directing someone to another site.

`Response.Redirect()` is good for when you want to redirect someone to another site.

Also, Fortify doesn't tend to like `Request.Params[]` due to its possible ambiguity. A careful attacker may be able, on some servers, to send a UTF-7 or non-printing version of a name as one of the request variables and let the name of the variable contain the actual XSS injection, or overwrite the GET-request value with a cookie of the same name. Make sure both the name and value are htmlencoded, and consider  using `Request.QueryString[parametername]` instead of `Request.Params[parametername]` to avoid more issues with Fortify.

Hopefully this gets you past your Fortify issues!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Fortify percieves Name as user defined and that will triger "Manupulation" error.  If it's true try to use predefined list if possible.